# Returning warning with output in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

getting warning with the output i cudnt find the reason please help me in this

```
     **Controller file  form_ctrl.php**

    <?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class form_ctrl extends CI_Controller {

        public function index()
        {
            //$this->load->view('welcome_message');
                 $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
                 $this->load->library('form_validation');
                 $this->load->model('data_model');

                    //$this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Username', 'required');
                  $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'name','required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]');
                    $this->form_validation->set_rules('pass', 'Password', 'required',
                            array('required' => 'You must provide a %s.')
                    );
                    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');
                    $this->form_validation->set_rules('mobile', 'Mobile', 'required');
                    $this->form_validation->set_rules('address', 'Address','required|min_length[5]');

                    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
                    {
                            $this->load->view('table');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            $this->load->view('results');
                            $name=$this->input->post('name');
                            $pass=$this->input->post('pass');
                            $email=$this->input->post('email');
                            $mobile=$this->input->post('mobile');
                             $address=$this->input->post('address');
                                 $data = array(
                                               'name' =>$name ,
                                               'pass' => $pass,
                                               'email' => $email,
                                               'mobile' => $mobile,
                                               'address' => $address
                                               );
                                $this->data_model->insert('form', $data);
                                $this->load->model('data_model');
                                 $val=$this->data_model->emp_getall();
                                 $data['query']=$val;
                                //print_r($data);exit;
                                     $this->load->view('results',$data);


                                           }
            }
    }


    **model file data_model.php**

    <?php
    class Data_model extends CI_Model {

        function __construct() { 
            parent::__construct (); 
        }

        public function insert($tableName,$data){

           return $this->db->insert($tableName, $data);

        }
        function emp_getall()
          {
               $this->load->database();
               $query=$this->db->get('form');
               if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
               $results = $query->result();
               }
              return $results;
          }
    }


    ?>


**view file results.php** 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<table width="100%" border="1px">
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td>Mobile</td>
        <td>Address</td>
        <td>Action</td>
        </tr>
         <?php
        foreach ($query as $val) {
            ?>
       <tr>
            <td><?php echo $val->name; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $val->email; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $val->mobile;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $val->address; ?></td>
            <td><a href="basic/update?uid=<?php echo $val->id; ?>">Edit</a>||<a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>delete/index/<?php echo $val->id; ?>">link</a></td>

        </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
    </body>
</html>


problem is that when m getting the results from view it showing me the warning with the result: 
first warning:
A PHP Error was encountered
    Severity: Notice
    Message: Undefined variable: query
    Filename: views/results.php
    Line Number: 16
```

second warning:
    A PHP Error was encountered
        Severity: Warning
        Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
        Filename: views/results.php
        Line Number: 16

```
and page also not redirecting to the next url that is results.php.what is the issue in this code y m getting warning and why page is not redirecting
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have loaded view page twice in the same  controller

```
$this->load->view('results');
```

And

```
 $this->load->view('results',$data);
```

Remove the first one

> $this->load->view('results',$data);

Answer (score 0):

Try changing query to results!!!

and also use error_reporting(0);(in controller inside function __construct)

foreach (**$results** as $val)